# Randomly placing a string into a 2d array

Tags: javascript

I need to create a 2D array and then randomly generate two numbers which will be the row and column that an X will be . I need to place four of them and they need to be hidden since it is for a game where the user guesses where they are.

```
char[][]gameBoard= new char [10][10];

int row= (int) (Math.random()*9+1);
int col=(int) (Math.random()*9+1);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j <     10; j++){

                      if(i==row&&j==col) 
                            System.out.print("[X]");


                    else
                         System.out.print("[ ]");

                System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Your 2D array is just the Data representation of your board state, `they need to be hidden since it is for a game` that is part of the View layer and you will have to handle that separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
const FILLED_FIELD = 'X'
function placeX(array) {
    const width = array.length - 1;
    const height = array[0].length - 1;
    const targetX = Math.round(Math.random() * width); //Pick a random number between 0, and the width of the array
    const targetY = Math.round(Math.random() * height); //Pick a random number between 0, and the height of the array
    if (array[targetX][targetY] === FILLED_FIELD) return placeX(array); //If the choosed place is already occupied, try again
    array[targetX][targetY] = FILLED_FIELD; //Otherwise fill a field
}
```

Technically not a perfect implementation, but will do the job. Just pass your 2D array to the function and it will randomly place X, ignoring places where X is already placed.